# Upgrading Sage to V3 problems

Tags: zen-cart, opayo

I am running zencart and use an add on module for sagepay form.  I have just upgraded this to the latest version which should comply to v3 but when I log into mysagepay it still says I need to upgrade to V3.  Is there somewhere else I should be going to make the changes?  I have a copy of the technical guide for migrating from v2.23 to v3 which tells me the changes I need to make but I don't know where I need to go to make these changes.  I am sure this is really simple but I am struggling.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you have a transaction ID (that you believe to be at 3.00) to hand and give Sage Pay a call - they can check the protocol value for you, so you can be sure you have upgraded successfully (MSP isn't always 100% reliable in the messages once you have upgraded!)